# fastest way to serialize numpy ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, serialization

I have a constant flow of medium sized `ndarray`s (each around 10-15mb in memory) on which I use `ndarray.tobytes()` before I send it to the next part of the pipeline.

Currently it takes about 70-100ms per array serialization.

I was wondering, is this the fastest that this could be done or is there a faster (maybe not as pretty) way to accomplish that?

clarification: arrays are images, next step in pipeline is some CPP function, I don't want to save them as a file.

Comment: What is the next step?  You write it to disk?  A C++ function needs it?  You send it on the network?  It would also help to understand the previous step, where do these arrays come from?

Comment: Youre right, I added some clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to serialize them at all!  You can let C++ read the memory directly.  One way is to invoke a C++ function with the PyObject which is your NumPy array.  Another is to let C++ allocate the NumPy array in the first place and populate the elements in Python before returning control to C++, for which I have some open source code built atop Boost Python that you can use: https://github.com/jzwinck/pccl/blob/master/NumPyArray.hpp

Your goal should be "zero copy" meaning you never copy the bytes of the array, you only copy references to the array or data within it plus the dimensions.

Comment: I think the first solution is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: How did you share the memory between C++ and python? A memory mapped file? Are you using a file backing store? As far as I know, at least in linux, you can only use a file-based memory mapped file to share memory between C++ and python. Do you know something I missed? I was forced to use a socket instead of shared mem, for this reason, and I'd love to do it with shared memory if possible.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey In OP's case I think the Python and C++ code might be all in one process, so no memory mapped file required.  `shm_open()` is one solution if you have two separate processes and neither is the parent of the other.